# Type Mismatch Error using AverageIf in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I keep getting Type Mismatch error (Run-time Error 13) from the last line below.
The data is contained in a csv file.
Column B has integers from 0-10.
Column C has decimal numbers from -1 to 1

```vb
Dim xl As New Excel.Application
Dim wb As New Excel.Workbook
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\...\Fake.csv")
Debug.Print (Application.WorksheetFunction.AverageIf(wb.Sheets(1).range("B2:B30"), 1, wb.Sheets(1).range("C2:C30")))
```

From the official document, `arg3` should be a variant. So I tried the code below, but the same error popped up.

```vb
Dim DirArray As Variant
DirArray = wb.Sheets(1).range("C2:C30").Value
Debug.Print (Application.WorksheetFunction.AverageIf(wb.Sheets(1).range("B2:B30"), 1, DirArray))
```

Can someone help please? Thanks

Comment: Your first version uses the same range (B2:B30) for both the criteria and sum ranges.

Comment: I don't see how you could get error 13 with this code. Depending on what the cells contain, you may get error 1004, but not 13.

Comment: I meant range (C2:C30) in arg3. That was a typo. Thanks for pointing out Tim

Comment: What happens if you replace "DirArray" in your Debug.Print line with "wb.Sheets(1).range("C2:C30").Value"?  And maybe remove the .value part?

Comment: Note - remove the outer parentheses: `Debug.Print Application...`

Comment: Tried both. Same error. Thanks @MichaelBeck

Comment: No problem.  Are you trying to average the two columns together?  Or each individually?  I got the impression from the documentation that arg3 isn't required so it would use values in arg1.

Comment: What is the result when you just type =AVERAGEIF(B2:B30,1,C2:C30) in the sheet?